# Using SELECT sub-query inside jsonb_array_elements_text function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, subquery, psql, jsonb

I have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) user_id, timestamp
FROM entries 
WHERE user_id in (1,2)
AND entry_type IN(
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(
    SELECT entry_types 
    FROM users INNER JOIN orgs
    ON org_id = orgs.id 
    WHERE users.id = 1
  )
);
```

I'm getting a syntax error at or near select

> syntax error at or near "select" LINE 1: ... entry_type in( select
> jsonb_array_elements_text(***s***elect ent.

The field entry_types is a JSONB field, so I am trying to convert it to text in order to use it in the WHERE IN clause.

PostgreSQL 13.0

This sub-query within jsonb_array_elements_text

```
SELECT entry_types 
    FROM users INNER JOIN orgs
    ON org_id = orgs.id 
    WHERE users.id = 1
```

Returns a single JSONB entry like this:

```
                entry_types                     
--------------------------------------------  
["type1", "type2", "type3"]
```

I'm simply trying to use the array of text values returned there as the criteria inside the WHERE IN clause.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results and an explanation of the purpose of the query. It is not obvious.

Comment: @GMB I added some detail, let me know if that's sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error seems to point somewhere else, so maybe I am wrong, but the problem I see is a missing pair of parentheses around the subquery:

```
jsonb_array_elements_text((SELECT ...))
```